# XAML to C# conversion tool

Tags: c#, xaml, baml

Is there a XAML to C# conversion tool?
I have a control template defined in XAML, but I want to create this template and it's styles using C#, so I can obfuscate the code version (since I can't obfuscate the XAML/BAML).

Answer (score 2):

There is no tool that I am aware of that converts XAML to C# in such a way it still produces WPF (or WF depending on which XAML you talking about).

That said you want obfuscate the XAML, and there are tools that do that. One I heard of is called {smartassembly} .NET Obfuscator 3.0 - http://www.smartassembly.com/

Comment: McLean: Good point in general, but you sure [{sa} is the best example to illustrate the point](http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/Content.aspx?p=SmartAssembly&c=SmartAssembly/help/5.5/SA_wpf.htm&toc=SmartAssembly/help/5.5/toc1210451.htm) ?

Comment: Doesnt that article suggest that SA does _NOT_ support X/BAML obfuscation (at least two others do) ? (I could easily be wrong- I havent researched this in any depth)